# Let a, b be two complex numbers in the left half-plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$\int f(z) \leq 1$ and M-T suggest \exists c$

Comment: The relation cannot be strict as you could take $a=b$.

Comment: It is a little hard to follow what you are doing above, and there are many mistakes.

Comment: You need to replace $<$ by $\le$ for a start. You have $|\cos x + i \sin x -1 |^2 = \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$ which is incorrect. You need to distinguish what you wish to prove from what is part of the proof. You need to justify the inequalities with question marks. Since $| \overline{z}| = |z|$ you can assume $a>b$ from the start.

Comment: I guess the strict inequality is meant to be here, but under the condition that $a\ne b$.

Comment: Please rollback the last edits, because now you have removed everything.

Answer (score 4):

The geometric view is that $|a-b|$ is the length of a curve between $e^{ia}$ and $e^{ib}$ - namely, the curve $e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[a,b]$ (or $[b,a]$, depending on the order of the values.)

But the shortest distance between two points is the linear distance, which is for these points $\left|e^{ib}-e^{ia}\right|$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a = b$, its trivial. Assume $a > b$, then: $|e^{ia} - e^{ib}| = |\cos a -\cos b + i(\sin a - \sin b)| = \sqrt{2-2\cos(a-b)}= 2\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{a-b}{2}\right)\right| < 2\left(\dfrac{a-b}{2}\right)= a-b$ and this last inequality is true since the inequality $x > \pm \sin x$ is true for $x > 0$

Comment: You can use the mean value theorem to show that $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$. Namely, $\sin x - 0 = x\cos\theta $ for some $\theta\in(0,x)$. So $|\sin x|\leq x$.

Comment: How can one assume $a \gt b$ for "*two complex numbers in the left half-plane*"?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t) = e^{it}$, then $|f'(t)| = 1$, and so by the mean value theorem,
$|f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$.

Since there seems to be some discomfort with my use of the mean value theorem,
here is the same result in a different guise:

$|f(t)-f(s)| = | \int_s^t f'(\tau) d \tau | \le \int_s^t |f'(\tau)| d \tau = |t-s|$.

Comment: Why not? I just did.

Comment: @copper.hat  Perhaps he means the mean value theorem doesn't hold for complex valued functions. It does hold with a dot, though.

Comment: Sure it does, $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \le \sup_{z \in [x,y]} \|{\partial f(z) \over \partial z}  \|\| x-y\|$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: downvote seems hasty, his answer is correct. If derivative a differentiable function on a compact set (e.g torus) (even complex valued) is bounded uniformly by some C, then the function is C-lipschitz, you prove this by mean-value theorem. even in complex case, you separate into real/complex part and apply triangle inequality?

Comment: @copper.hat I know that.  I was trying to understand what the OP means. Compare with the example in the last line [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement). It would be better to explain to the OP how to modify the statement so that what you write is naturally deduced. As I say, you just need to replace usual multiplication with the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to comment on your solution instead. It looks good, but I have two comments

1. You do not actually need Case 2, since Case 3 works for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$.
2. The last argument "because of its taylor series" is not very convincing. It is better to do something like this: denote $f(x)=x^2+2\cos x-2$ and show that the minimum is zero. The derivative is
   $$
   f'(x)=2(x-\sin x).
   $$
   Here we see that $f'(x)=0$ only at zero, $f'(x)<0$ for negative $x$ and $f'(x)>0$ for positive $x$. Hence, the function is strictly decreasing first to $f(0)=0$ and then strictly increasing. Thus, $f(x)>0$ for all $x\ne 0$.

P.S. An interpretation of $|e^{ix}-1|$ as the chord length and of $|x|$ as the arc length of the angle $x$ radians on the unit circle opens a possibility for a geometric proof of the fact.

P.S.S. If you want to go via Taylor series then you should make it more explicit as
$$
\cos x=1-x^2/2+\sin(\theta x)x^3/6,\quad 0\le\theta\le 1
$$
and then comment on positivity of $\sin(\theta x)x$.

Comment: @Marmar Yes, I understand, but to prove that $\cos x=1-x^2/2+...>1-x^2/2$  you will need to prove that the residual $...$ is positive. Taking the Lagrange's form of the residual it is not hard to do, but I mean that it *needs* to be done in more details that just saying "from the Taylor's series".

Comment: @Marmar My second comment is the standard way how we prove inequalities with the first year students at my university. My P.S.S. comment is how you can proceed with the Taylor series following your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: For $h>0,1-\cos h < h^2/2.$ Proof: Since $\sin t < t$ for $t>0,$ we have

$$1-\cos h = \int_0^h\sin t \, dt < \int_0^h t \, dt = h^2/2.$$

Thm: $|e^{ih}-1| < h$ for $h>0.$ Proof: $|e^{ih}-1|^2 = 2(1-\cos h) < h^2,$ where we have applied the lemma. Now take square roots.

Corollary: If $a<b,$ then $|e^{ib} - e^{ia}| < b-a.$ Proof:

$$|e^{ib} - e^{ia}| = |e^{ia}(e^{i(b-a)} - 1)| = |e^{i(b-a)} - 1| < b-a,$$

the last inequality coming from the theorem.